# Whats the best approach to restoring access to a user who can't access their email?

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to think of different methods to restore an account to a user who can no longer access their email. For my project, regaining account access is very important, throwing away an account is not an option.

Current thoughts

1. Make users wait a set time period (I'm thinking about 180 days) and each week email their email to see if theres any response (in the event it's an attempt to attack the account). (not overly fond of this one)
2. Allow the users to submit personal information like an ID or Passport or possibly a video of themselves. (would need to do this before losing their account info)
3. Allow them to set a backup email
4. Allow them to set a backup password (where if you have this password you can get into the account regardless if you have the email or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Secondary email, phone number, 2FA authentification, or security questions should do the trick in most cases.

Another option is if the user is required to fill in his first and last name when signing up, upload a selfie then you could unlock their account if they submit an ID ( but the platform should be trustable enough for users to be open to upload their ID for verification. )